# focus input before DOM is load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I focus an text input when it is visible which is probably before the whole DOM is ready? I only have to possibility to run a script before the DOM started loading.  The reason I want to do this is that the user wants to start typing until the input is visible and loading the DOM takes a while.

I would like to do it with jQuery.

Greetings!

Comment: it's out of question to focus on something which is not exist!

Comment: I don't understand how you would possibly apply focus *before* the DOM is ready. What would you apply focus to if it's not there?

Comment: so there is no possibility to focus a text input with a browser plugin before the **whole** DOM is ready?

Comment: Why do you need to do it before the DOM is ready?

Comment: because loading the DOM takes a few seconds and this is too long in my case. the user wants to start typing until the input is visible...

Comment: By definition, you CANNOT operate on the DOM until it is loaded.  It simply isn't there yet.  So what you're asking for is simply not possible in any way.  The earliest you can possibly run a script that can affect an element of the DOM is to place a `<script>` tag immediately after that element in the DOM.  That's the absolute earliest that a script can operate on an element in the DOM.  Before that, the element doesn't exist yet and thus it cannot receive focus.

Answer (score 2):

No need to involve JavaScript. Just use [the autofocus attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control:-the-autofocus-attribute).

```
<input name="foo" autofocus>
```

Comment: actually I am using a plugin so this is no solution in my case. I need to realise it with a script which runs before the DOM even started loading. Sorry, I didn't mention that in my question.

Comment: it is nice approach but autfocus is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
 <input id="username" type="text" name="username"/>
 <script>
   $("#username").focus();
 </script>
```

after declaring DOM in html write your scripts

supported in major Browsers

Comment: actually I am using a plugin so this is no solution in my case. I need to realise it with a script which runs before the DOM even started loading. Sorry, I didn't mention that in my question.